# Predual of von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras

I know that each separable finite von Neumann has separable predual. Can some one give me an example of a non-separable finite von Neumann algebra with separable predual?

Answer (score 8):

*(Disclaimer: "separable" for the predual means in the norm topology, while for a von Neumann algebra it means in the sot topology)*

Any von Neumann algebra with separable predual is separable. If the predual of $M $ is separable, the (countable) direct sum of the (one-dimensional) GNS representations over a dense subset of the unit ball of the normal states gives a faithful normal representation  $M\to B (H) $ with $H $ separable. And $B (H) $ is separable (because $K (H) $ is). As the sot is metrizable on bounded sets of $B (H) $, the unit ball of $M $ is separable (in a metric space, subset of separable is separable),  and so $M $ is separable.

When $M$ acts on a separable Hilbert space, it has separable predual. This is because it can be shown that normal linear functionals are determined by square-summable sequences.

It is not true that $M$ separable implies separable predual. An example is $M=\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$. This $M$ cannot act on a separable Hilbert space because it has uncountably many pairwise orthogonal projections. And/or one can easily check that its predual $\ell^1(\mathbb R)$ is not separable (the canonical basis is uncountable and any two elements are at distance $2$). And, being, abelian, $M$ is finite. And $M$ is [$\sigma$-weak separable](https://mathoverflow.net/a/304068/3698).

In summary, the implications run like this: for $M\subset B(H)$,
$$
\text{$H$ separable}\iff \text{ separable predual}\implies  \text{$M$ separable.}
$$

Comment: I can't understand why if a Hilbert space $H$ is separable then the space $B(H)$ is separable too.

Comment: Because $K (H) $ is separable  (even in norm) and dense. Concretely, $E=\{E_{kj}\} $ is a set of matrix units (countable because $H $ is separable) then  the span of $E $ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q $ is dense.

Comment: $K(H)$ is closed in $B(H)$ and not dense

Comment: From the first line in the answer:  *(Disclaimer: "separable" for the predual means in the norm topology, while for a von Neumann algebra it means in the sot topology)*. The norm topology does not see the von Neumann algebra structure. $K(H)$ is dense in $B(H)$ in the right topologies; easy consequence of the Double Commutant Theorem.