# Gelfand-Naimark and the Calkin Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin_algebra,  "The Gelfand-Naimark-Segal construction implies that the Calkin algebra is isomorphic to an algebra of operators on a nonseparable Hilbert space."

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional, complex, separable Hilbert space. By applying the Gelfand–Naimark-Segal Construction we can obtain an injective *-homomorphism $\phi: B(H)/K(H) \rightarrow B(H')$ for some Hilbert space $H'$, where $B(H)/K(H)$ is the Calkin algebra. I want to show that $H'$ here is not separable in this case.

Let's try proving it by contradiction.

Suppose there exists a countable dense subset of $H'$. And let $\{ e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Q}}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$.

I know that there exists uncountable many infinite subsets $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $E_{\alpha } \cap E_{\beta}$ is finite for $\alpha \ne \beta$.
I was suggested to consider the orthogonal projections $P_{\alpha}$ of $H$ onto span $\{e_n: n \in E_{\alpha}\}$... But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any references or suggestions will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, how do you prove the statemt there exist uncountable many inifinite subsets $\{E_\alpha\_{\alpha\in I}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $E_\alpha \cap E_\beta$ is finite if $\alpha \neq\beta$

Comment: @juaaan, basically a set theoretic argument, you know that there are $\aleph_1$ many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then you have to count how many finite subsets are there, not more than $\aleph_0$, then you check the final details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically done. Take
$$
P_\alpha=\sum_{n\in E_\alpha}e_n.
$$
If $\pi:B(H)\to B(H)/K(H)$ is the quotient map, you have $\pi(P_\alpha P_\beta)=0$ when $\alpha\ne \beta$ since $P_\alpha P_\beta$ is finite-rank.

So $\{\pi(P_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ is an uncountable family of pairwise orthogonal projections in $B(H)/K(H)$.

Comment: What is the contradiction here? Thank you for your help!

Comment: $\|P_\alpha-P_\beta\|=1$.

Comment: Where did we use the assumption that  $H'$ has a countable dense set and that $\phi: B(H) \rightarrow B(H)/K(H)$ is an injective *-homorphism? I really appreciate your time for helping me!

Comment: The family $\{\phi(P_\alpha)\}$ is a pairwise orthogonal family of projections in $H'$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see why $\| P_{\alpha} - P_{\beta}\|=1$ is a contradiction...

Comment: If you have a metric space and an uncountable family of elements at distance 1 from each other, the space cannot be separable.

Comment: @Martin, the projections are in $B(H')$ not $B(H)$ no ?

Comment: No, they are in $B(H)/K(H)$. Their images under $\phi$ will form an uncountable family of pairwise orthogonal projections in $B(H')$.

Comment: thank you, you are using the fact that $\phi$ is injective to use the inverse ?

Comment: There are no inverses involved. $\phi$ is a $*$-monomorphism, that's all you need.

Comment: thanks, I see it now, you are also using $\|\pi(P_\alpha)- \pi(P_\beta)\|= \|P_\alpha- P_\beta \|= 1$ since $\pi$ is a an isometric *-homomorphism.

Comment: and no non-separable algebra can be represented by operators on a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes. But [separability is a bit tricky to consider](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1764532/22857), so it is easier/clearer so say that the subalgebra has uncountably many pairwise orthogonal projections, which is impossible in a separable Hilbert space. And, in this case, it is direct as it is what one proves.