# Concrete realization of quotient $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, quotient-spaces

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of the bounded operators $B(H)$ on some Hilbert space $H$. Let $J$ be a proper closed $2$-sided ideal of $A$. Then one knows that $A/J$ is another $C^*$-algebra.

By the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, one also knows that $A/J$ is $*$-isomorphic to a $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H')$ for some Hilbert space $H'$.

**Question:** Is there a "natural" choice of $H'$?

This seems like a natural and basic question, but having looked around a bit, it seems that an answer may not be straightforward. In particular, in the case where $A=B(H)$ and $J=K(H)$ for $H$ separable, the Gelfand-Naimark-Segal construction gives a [non-separable example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089692/gelfand-naimark-and-the-calkin-algebra) of $H'$. But I would be interested if there are any references where this is discussed further.

Comment: Interesting question as stated, but I wonder, regarding the term "natural," do you seek nice universal properties in some categorical sense? Or do you mean something like separability of the space that $A/J$ is faithfully represented as acting on?  (I am not sure if these goals are compatible but am not an expert in this area.)  Or both/either when available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you consider "natural". If $A$ is separable, then you can take $H$ separable, which allows you to take $H'=H$; but I don't think you'll have any relation between those concrete realizations of $A$ and $A/J$. It is probably worth remarking that the concrete presentation of the Hilbert spaces $H$ and $H'$ can very a lot, and while some representations are better than others, there is no obvious "best" one.

For a kind of generic example, let $A=C^*(\mathbb F_\infty)$, the universal C$^*$-algebra of the free group on infinitely many generators. This C$^*$-algebra is *universal*, in the sense that any separable C$^*$-algebra is a quotient of it. Being separable, $A$ has a faithful state, $\phi$, so we can do GNS and represent $A\subset B(L^2(A,\phi))$. Because $A$ has countably many generators with no relations, any separable C$^*$-algebra $A_0$ is a quotient of $A$. So you can choose any separable C$^*$-algebra $A_0$, represent it on a Hilbert space $H'$, in one of many many ways, and conclude that one cannot expect any natural relation between $H'$ and $H=L^2(A,\phi)$.